# Update text inside text file?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I can't find in [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) and [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) methods of Google Drive API, where should I put actual text that I want to be inside my text file. Where is this parameter?

With this query I only create empty file:

```
  await window.gapi.client.drive.files.create({
    resource: {
      'name': `${knowledgeFile.id}.txt`,
      'parents': [`${srcDataFolderId}`]
    },
    media: {
      mimeType: 'text/plain',
      body: convertHTMLToPlainText(knowledgeFileHTML)
    },
    fields: 'id'
  })
```

Comment: you need to use the Google Docs api to change the text in a google document file, or google sheets api to change the data in a google sheet.   For a .txt file you will probably have to convert it to a google doc.  Or download it and edit it locally.

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### After creating a text file on your drive, you can update its content with the [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) request

To do so

- Specify the new content as a `string`
- Transform the content string into a byte array
- Get the existing file by its `id`
- Read the file as binary string with [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)
- Create a new file metadara as a bytearray merging the old and the new contents
- Perform an `Files:Update` request specifying the new file metadata as request `body`

**Sample**

```js
function updateFile() {
    var fileId = "YOUR FILE ID";
    var contentString = "Hello world";
    var contentArray = new Array(contentString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) {
        contentArray[i] = contentString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(contentArray);
    var newData = new Blob([byteArray], {
        type: 'text/plain'
    });
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
        'fileId': fileId
    });
    request.execute(function(oldData) {
        var boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
        var delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        var close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(newData);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var contentType = newData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
            var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
            var multipartRequestBody =
                delimiter + 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' + JSON.stringify(oldData) + delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' + 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' + '\r\n' + base64Data + close_delim;

            var request = gapi.client.request({
                'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/' + fileId,
                'method': 'PUT',
                'params': {
                    'uploadType': 'multipart',
                    'alt': 'json'
                },
                'headers': {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
                },
                'body': multipartRequestBody
            });

            request.execute();
        }
    });

}
```